# How can I create a set-once app-level action that isn't enforced via runtime exceptions or swallowing second-sets?

Tags: c#, static, appsettings

I'd like to be able to specify an `Action<string>` at the app level that my library could then use for progress reporting.  `ConfigurationManager.AppSettings` only allows `XmlSerializeable`s, and `Action`s are not that.

The motivation is that console apps might just write to the console, webapps perhaps to a trace, and forms perhaps to files or a particular field, the point is the app should be able to configure it imo.

My approach currently is to have in the library a `LibSettings` class that has a static settable `Action<string>`.  That means anyone can set it elsewhere too, which poses potential for bugs.

At first I thought maybe a static constructor (with parameters) would do but it turns out you can't call static constructors explicitly and you certainly can't give them parameters.

Is there any way to achieve my goal of being able to specify the Feedback action once and only onc in some sort of custom app settings, and not throw a runtime exception on second setting, or swallow the second setting?  That is essentially like a singleton property of my design when I design it.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Well, create a property and on the Setter just check if the backed field is null, if it's null then set it and if it's not null discard the value silently.

Comment: @Gusman: Sorry I just updated it.  I don't want it to swallow it either as that would mean someone intended to update that setting and it just didn't.

Comment: Hmmm, then i can't understand what you mean with *my goal of being able to specify the Feedback action once and only onc in some sort of custom app settings, and not throw a runtime exception on second setting*

Comment: @Gusman: I'll update it but let me describe now: essentially I want a way to  be able to have an app-level property that once i set it, it becomes readonly and all future attempts to set it lead to a compiler error.  Perhaps this simply is impossible.

Comment: If I understood it right, you want to set it *externally* to the owner class but at the second time it's tried to set throw a compilation error? that's just impossible. If the set is internal to the class then you can use a private setter or a readonly field.

Comment: @Gusman: so a readonly field is very similar to what I want, where you can only set it via the constructor, but actually what I want is something like a static readonly field OR some way to make sure that an instance with the readonly Action is always the same once it's created.

Answer (score 1):

Serializing and deserializing a delegate usually isn't a good idea, as it easily leads to pretty serious security concerns (see [arbitrary code execution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arbitrary_code_execution)).

Instead I would recommend having a `enum` or similar serializable type that identifies a number of statically defined functions and convert between them. Something like this:

```
public enum FeedbackAction
{
    Console,
    Trace,
    ...
}

public static class FeedbackActions
{
    public static void Console(string text) { ... }
    public static void Trace(string text) { ... }

    public static Action<string> GetAction(FeedbackAction action)
    {
        switch (action)
        {
            case FeedbackAction.Console:
                return Console;
            case FeedbackAction.Trace:
                return Trace;
            default:
                throw new ArgumentException("Invalid feedback action.", nameof(action));
        }
    }
}
```

Now whenever you're trying to use the app setting, just call `FeedbackActions.GetAction` to convert between your `enum` values and the appropriate `Action<string>`.

For example:

```
public static class Feedback
{
    public static Action<string> feedbackAction;
    public static object syncLock = new object();

    public static void ProvideFeedback(string text)
    {
        if (feedbackAction == null)
        {
            // synchronize to avoid duplicate calls
            lock (syncLock)
            {
                if (feedbackAction == null)
                {
                    var value = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["FeedbackAction"];
                    feedbackAction = FeedbackActions.GetAction(value);
                }
            }
        }

        feedbackAction(text);
    }
}
```

This way you can safely call `Feedback.ProvideFeedback`, and its behavior will be driven by the app/web.config file.

---

If you need to make a solution that's flexible enough to handle almost any feedback action, I'd strongly recommend reading up on [inversion of control](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inversion_of_control) in general and the [Managed Extensibility Framework (MEF)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460648(v=vs.110).aspx) in particular. A full implementation would be a bit too complex to provide here, but in general it would look a bit like this:

```
public interface IFeedbackAction
{
    void ProvideFeedback(string text);
}

public interface IFeedbackMetadata
{
    string Name { get; }
}

[Export(typeof(IFeedbackAction)), ExportMetadata("Name", "Console")]
public interface ConsoleFeedbackAction : IFeedbackAction { ... }

[Export(typeof(IFeedbackAction)), ExportMetadata("Name", "Trace")]
public interface TraceFeedbackAction : IFeedbackAction { ... }

public static class Feedback
{
    [ImportMany]
    public IEnumerable<Lazy<IFeedbackAction, IFeedbackMetadata>> FeedbackActions { get; set; }

    private IFeedbackAction feedbackAction;

    public static void ProvideFeedback(string text)
    {
        if (feedbackAction == null)
        {
            // synchronize to avoid duplicate calls
            lock (syncLock)
            {
                if (feedbackAction == null)
                {
                    var value = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["FeedbackAction"];
                    feedbackAction = GetFeedbackAction(value);
                }
            }
        }

        feedbackAction.ProvideFeedback(text);
    }

    private static IFeedbackAction GetFeedbackAction(string name)
    {
        return FeedbackActions
            .First(l => l.Metadata.Name.Equals(name)).Value;
    }
}
```

With this method, consumers would be able to provide their own implementation of `IFeedbackAction`, decorated with the appropriate `[Export]` and `[ExportMetadata]` attributes, and simply specify use of their custom actions in the app/web.config file.

Comment: Thanks.  This is also an approach I had considered but it doesn't allow me to pass (to the library) sometihng like FormTextBox.Text = s, so my library would only be able to handle X possibilities.  It's a good idea though thank you.

Comment: @user420667 It sounds like you need the flexibility to handle aribitrary implementations of your feedback action. This sounds like an ideal candidate for inversion of control (IoC). see my updated answer.

Comment: still trying to understand your updated answer.  I'ver heard of IoC before but never used it and certainly never heard of the MEF before.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, let's see if I inderstood all right.

Let's suppose this is your config class:

```
public static class LibSettings
{
    public static readonly Action<string> TheAction{ get; private set; }

    static LibSettings()
    {
        var action = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["libAction"];

        switch(action)
        {
           case "console":

               TheAction = ConsoleAction;
               break;

           case "web":

               TheAction = WebAction;
               break;

           //And as many as you need...
        }
    }

    private static void ConsoleAction(string Parameter)
    {
       //Whatever it does...
    }

    private static void WebAction(string Parameter)
    {
       //Whatever it does...
    }

}
```

Is this what you meant? it will be only set once whenever you access any property of the class, it cannot be modified externally and will change the Action upon an AppSeting record.

Ok, let's go with another approach. Now we will have two classes a temporal holder where you will set the action you want and the current settings class.

```
public static class TemporalHolder 
{
    public static Action<string> HeldAction{ get; set; }
}

public static class LibSettings
{
    public static readonly Action<string> TheAction;
    static LibSettings()
    {
        TheAction = TemporalHolder.HeldAction;
    }
    public static void Init()
    { 
        /*Just do nothing as we will use it to fire the constructor*/ 
    }
}
```

And now, to use it, just seth the action to the temporal holder and call anithing static on LibSettings:

```
TemporalHolder.Action = (your function);
LibSettings.Init();
```

And voila! no errors on second settings, it cannot be changed on runtime and cannot be reasigned. are all the conditions met?

Comment: Thanks.  Yes this is along the lines of waht I want, and similar to @p.s.w.g's answer.  The only thing is is that it suffers the same problem of not beeing able to pass in something like FormTextField.Text = string.

Comment: Okokoko, i have an idea on how to achieve exactly what you want, let me update this :D.

Comment: Great thanks.  I came up with a very similar solution but I guess it still suffers the swallowing of what happens when you set TemporalHolder.HeldAction twice and also it means you have to get the order right (that is you have to set TemporalHolder.HeldAction before ever looking at LibSettings).  I still think it's a great solution though and the naming helps.  Thanks a lot!

Comment: Well, technically what you have here is what you asked, the field which is set is *not* possible to change a second time and will throw an exception if you try to change it, that field is LibSettings.TheAction not TemporalHolder.HeldAction :)
Yes yes yes, I understand what you say, I was just being pedantic XD

Comment: Yes, technically :-p.

Comment: Cool so I ended up going with something almost idential to this except that I made the Action inside of a singleton (so there could be other readonly things), and put the "TemporalHolder" in its own namespace (AppOnly) that the library wouldn't use but the app would, and the LibSettings internal to the library.  Thank you!